# Search inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement autocomplete to my application using Local Storage. 
Is there way to search inside an array of words using 'LIKE %value%' condition?

```
var autocompleteArr = ['two', 'three', 'twenty two', 'twelve'];
mySearchMethod(autocompleteArr, 'tw'); //['two', 'twenty two', 'twelve']
```

Comment: use regex to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in partial search use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
function match(value) {
  return value.match(/.*tw.*/);
}
var filtered = ['two', 'three', 'twenty two', 'twelve'].filter(match);
// filtered is ['two', 'twenty two', 'twelve']
```

If interested in exact match, then **`indexOf`** will do.

Comment: Just for the heck of it, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5rhn7mf3/) is a simple fiddle putting this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexOf to check if a string contains another.

```
var autocompleteArr = ['two', 'three', 'twenty two', 'twelve'];

function mySearchMethod(haystack, needle) {

    arr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
        if (haystack[i].indexOf(needle)) {
            arr.push(haystack[i]);
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: @raghavendra Thanks. This is a little basic, but for some people it is far more easy to understand. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function arrayContains(autocompleteArr, searchString){
  var answerArray = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < autocompleteArr.length; i++){
    if(autocompleteArr[i].indexOf(searchString) != -1){
      answerArray.push(autocompleteArr[i]);
    }
  }
  return answerArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this combining regular expressions and `Array.filter`:

```
var input = ... // get the user input from somewhere
var autocompleteArr = ['two', 'three', 'twenty two', 'twelve'];
var suggestions = autocompleteArr.filter(function(el){
    return new Regexp(input).test(el);
});
```

If you want to match from the beginning of the typing, change this line to:

```
return new Regexp("^"+input).test(el);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do something like this

```
var autocompleteArr = ['two', 'three', 'twenty two', 'twelve'];
var autocomplete = function(word) {
    return autocompleteArr.filter(function(ele) {return ele.match(".*"+word+".*");})
}


autocomplete("tw") // ["two", "twenty two", "twelve"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jkn6xgr7/2/

Comment: what is _ here can pls explain it

Comment: _ is an object provided by underscore.js

Comment: updated the code the do it without underscore. I saw the underscorejs tag on the question that why I thought to do it with underscorejs.